# unpublishing user posts by default then the administrator publishes them

Tags: drupal

I created an entity form called Send post, A user fills in the form then submit the post to the admin. I then want a mechanism whereby if a user sends a post it will be automatically unpublished unless the admin publishes it. Is there a way I can do that using the features module!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your hook_node_presave() function and and check for user role , node type and what ever you want there and conditionally unpublish the node just before it's saved.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7

If I remember well you have to set property "status" to 0 to unpublish the node.

Comment: I would have loved to do that, now my problem is i don't understand module development that much yet. So i just thought there might be an easier way of solving the problem from the backend using the features module.

Comment: Didn't use features module, sorry. But you can try using drupal's actions & rules system if you want to avoid coding.

Comment: Oh alright, do you mind explaining how that works! please

Comment: Basically you create an action (if it doesn't exist already), like "unpublish content" or something. Then you should create  rule with rules interface. It's a bit too big for describing whole process in details here. Try finding some tutorials. https://www.drupal.org/node/1866108

Comment: Thanks for the help MilanG

Comment: MilanG may you please help me on how I can customize publish button module so that it applies to fields and not nodes. I don't mind coding, I'm very much prepared please help.

Comment: You create an module, let's call it "mytest". Then inside module file you place a function called "mytest_node_presave" and clear the cache. After that before any node is saved your function will be called and you will be able to change node data. You can also see role of current user so if it's in some specific role, you want you'll set node status to 0 (not published). Google a bit of how to create a module and how to make hook functions. It needs to much text to explain and is not related directly to this question.